# Folder structuring in boiler plate

Tags: angularjs, language-agnostic, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm trying to marshal a boiler plate for mobile app in angularjs. I plan it to be highly opinionated thus setting up some constrains for the app structure. Eventually bundling to an npm generator

I have come up with 2 generally found folder structures.

```
app
 - directives
 - controllers
 - services
 - views
 - styles
```

The second one being

```
app
 - login
 - register
 - notification
```

The latter being domain specific structuring. Which one is more agile and generic?

Comment: Domain specific structure will be a better approch as per my view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely the second one!

In medium/big applications, with the "by functionality" structure, you can better organize and maintain your code.

Read this, very very helpful, style guide ;)

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: Actually, John Papa recommends a mix between those two. Components (directives) and services should be separated. 'Functionality' are mainly views and their controllers.